# How do you get an ISRC from Apple Music on-device?

Tags: ios, apple-music, apple-musickit

Is there any way using MediaKit/MusicKit on iOS on-device to get an ISRC (International Standard Recording Code) from a `MPMediaItem` in a reliable way?

I know that MusicKit JS has this metadata, but is it hiding somewhere on iOS?